# Server configuration advice

Tags: configuration

I have the following server configuration:

- CPU 2 x Westmere-EP E5630 4C 80W 2.53G 12M 5.86GT/sec LGA1366 HT HF VT ITT TXT
- RAM 4 x 2GB 1333MHz DDR3 ECC Reg w/Parity CL9 DIMM DR, x8 w/Therm Sen (Intel)
- HDD 4 x 1 TB/SATA-7200-32mb -CONSTELLATION ES 7200.1
- Intel Server System SR2600URBRP. Includes: 750 watt redundant 1+0 high efficiency hot-swap PSU; 3 non-redundant fans; 1 riser card with 3 full-height PCI Express 2.0 x8 slots
- 750W Hot-Swap Power Supply Module
- Sony Optiarc ODD slim DVD-RW 8x SATA, black, bulk

The server would host a quite intensive sql web app with a few hundred clients/day and some reporting stuff.

That is the main application but there are several others that are not quite so demanding.

Any suggestions on what I should change? If anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's impossible to say since we don't know what "quite intensive" means and if you already have bottlenecks.

Anyway, what's most likely to help might if you have bottlenecks is

- Much more RAM
- Faster disks. Think a hardware RAID controller with 10K/15K RPM SAS disks or even SDD drives, in hot swap cases.
- I don't see if you have redundant power supplies. If not, it's irrelevant if the one you have is hot-swappable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply - yes there are bottlenecks and currently they are due because of the RAM (only 4GB) . Much appreciate the other replies too.

Answer (score 2):

You have quite slow disks for database. I would highly recommend SAS disks, if you have large database. If your database can fit to memory (after other memory requirements), then it doesn't matter.

CPU power is thing that can't be determined from your description.

8GB memory is good idea, and should be enough, unless you are running for example memory hungry Java servlets.

If you can, I would start with that server to check out what have to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

Also depends how you will arrange the 4 HDDs.

If you expect lot of read write operations, I suggest to organize them in Raid10 rather than Raid5